# Determining what the decision boundary will look like in various scenarios

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, classification, mathematical-statistics

[image]

I'm currently trying to work through this question, but not quite sure where to start. The cases I need to consider are (in turn):

(a): $lamda_0$ = 0, $lamda_1$ = 0, $lamda_2$ = $\infty$

(b): $lamda_0$ = $\infty$, $lamda_1$ = 0, $lamda_2$ = 0

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (a), $\theta_2$ will be chosen as $0$ since $\lambda_2=\infty$, and there is no other way to minimize the loss. Similarly, for (b), $\theta_0=0$.

(a) If we have $\theta_2=0$, the decision boundary will look like $\theta_1x_1+\theta_0=0$, i.e. the vertical line.

(b) If we have $\theta_0=0$, the decision boundary is $\theta_1x_1+\theta_2x_2=0$, a line passing from the origin.

For having a horizontal line as boundary, you need $\theta_2x_2+\theta_0=0$, where $\theta_1$ is forced to be $0$ due to $\lambda_1=\infty$.

Normally, you'd have a threshold in logistic regression, but here it is chosen as $\tau=0.5$ as I follow.